# How to initialize weights in tensorflow.contrib.layers conv2d

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I wrote a simple autoencoder using tensorflow library. 
[This is the sample code I have written for the network of the autoencoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAGfr.png)
What I dont get is how to introduce weights into this model as it is working now without any specific initialization?

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. The reasons are [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you for this

Comment: Code is removed. Could you post it back without the image ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weight initialization is being defined when creating a conv2d layer. In the API (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) there is a parameter in such function named `weights_initializer` that can be filled with a `tf.initializer` object and defines the way weights are initialized. By default, for TFv1.8, this is a `xavier_initializer` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer), but you could set it to any of the initializers included here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers. For example, if you want weight initialization to be constant with value 12345, you would write:

```
lays.conv2d(inputs, 32,[5,5], stride=2, padding="SAME", 
                   weights_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(12345))
```